# Am I stuck in a clan?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm stuck in a clan. I cannot leave. We cannot see the My Clan menu. It is all a blank white page.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest saving your progress to your Google Play account (if on android) or to your Facebook account (works on all operating systems). On IOS you can link to the Game centre. After saving your village you can delete and reinstall the game without a loss of progress.

If this doesn't solve the problem you can try to ask one of the clan members to kick you (if you know them in person).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have game center, try deleting and then re-installing the app and signing back in. Your progress should be saved and the bug fixed.